# WP_QUERY return all posts (regardless of permissions)

Tags: wordpress

I need to be able to show teaser content on the site for something that is gated behind a paywall. So I need WP_QUERY to return all posts, even if they are behind said paywall.

```
$query_args = [
    'post_type' => [TYPE_1, TYPE_2],
    'posts_per_page' => 1
];
// Only returns what I want when users are logged in.
// I need this to return the thing, even if users are logged out
return new \WP_Query($query_args);
```

What are my options?

Comment: Well, you already have the start of the solution in your code. Not sure what exactly you want us to tell you other than "loop over the results and display the title and maybe something else (like the thumbnail or the excerpt) and that's it" so please clarify.

Comment: I mean yeah sure, but it's only returning the posts that the current user is allowed to see. I want to return all of them.